# MSAL.js acquireTokenSilent API fails with error AADSTS70011 when logging in from a microsoft personal account

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, msal.js

I have registered an application with "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)" and trying to login with a personal account using msal.js.
The code is as following

```js
this.$msalInstance
        .loginPopup({scopes: ['user.read']})
        .then(() => {
          const myAccounts = this.$msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
          this.account = myAccounts[0];
          const accessTokenRequest = {
            scopes: [`${this.msalConfig.auth.clientId}/.default`],
            account: this.account
          };
          this.$msalInstance
            .acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest)
            .then(function(accessTokenResponse) {
              // Acquire token silent success
              let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
              }
```

The configuration is defined as below

```
msalConfig: {
  auth: {
    clientId: "1236664d-751d-4a0a-9a3d-13c332cb7e9b",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/app/login", 
    postLogoutRedirectUri: "/" 
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage"
  }
```

The "loginPopup" call succeeds,  but the "acquireTokenSilent" fails with the below error

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not
> valid. The scope '1236664d-751d-4a0a-9a3d-13c332cb7e9b/.default openid
> profile offline_access' is not valid - it refers to a resource which
> is not listed in the client's Required Resource Access and for which
> the user does not have any existing consent.

The error occurs only for personal account. It works with user from same or different organizations active directory.

Can someone give an idea on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'xxx/.default openid profile offline_access' is not valid - it refers to a resource which is not listed in the client's Required Resource Access and for which the user does not have any existing consent.

The error usually occurs if the scope is not properly configured in the Application and is passing the invalid scope to authorize.

- Make sure that the resources/scopes you are trying to pass is added in the Client application.

I got the same error when I tried to authorize users like below:

For **sample**, I used the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxxx/.default openid profile offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make sure to add the scope in the Application like below:

In the **`ServerrukApp`**, I exposed the API and added scope:

[image]

Make sure to add the **`ServerrukApp`** custom scope in the **`ClientrukApp`** API permission blade like below:

[image]

When I tried to sign-in with Microsoft Personal Account, it is successful:

[image]

[image]

If still issue persists, check the below:

Make sure the **`ClientrukApp`** API permission blade looks like this:

[image]

Otherwise, In the **`ServerrukApp`**, add the client application as authorized like below:

[image]

Make sure you have used **`common`** endpoint in all the code config files.

Comment: By adding the custom scope in the client app registration it did return correct token.